# Segmentation fault - Socket Programming - C

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write an echo server\client model in C. My code compiles but throws a segmentation fault error at run-time [I believe on the server side process]. When testing in CLion debug environment, the server process is able to execute the accept() system call and enter into a a waiting state until a client connects. Therefore, I believe that the segmentation fault error happens after the client makes the connect() system call.

Here are the relevant snippets of code (only the last part - not full program):

```
/* [6] LISTEN FOR CONNECTIONS ON BOUND SOCKET===================================================================== */
struct sockaddr_storage ample;    /* from Beej Guide 5.6 accept() */
socklen_t ample_sz = sizeof(ample);
fd_activeSock = accept(fd_listenSock, (struct sockaddr *)&established_SERV_param, &ample_sz);

if (fd_activeSock == -1)    /* Error checking */
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nNo forum for communication...\nTERMINATING PROCESS");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("\nCommunication Established! What's your sign??");
freeaddrinfo(established_SERV_param);    /* free up memory */

/* [7] ACCEPT A CONNECTION (BLOCKING)============================================================================= */

/* MAIN LOOP====================================================================================================== */
while(1)
{
    bzero(msg_incoming, 16);
    recv(fd_activeSock, msg_incoming, 16, 0);
    printf("%s", msg_incoming);
    send(fd_activeSock, msg_incoming, 16, 0);
}
```

When I run both programs in separate terminals (server process first, of course), the last print statement that runs before the error is:

`printf("\nCommunication Established! What's your sign??");`

The error is output to the server terminal. There is a core dump; for future issues, could someone suggest a beginners tutorial on combing through core dump files. Also, I have run the code with the freeaddrinfo() call commented out and still get a segmentation fault error so I do not believe that this is the issue. Why run it at all? I do not want memory leaks. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

*[recv()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/recv.html)* does not explicitly place a null terminator at the end of the buffer, but `printf()` expects one.

In the statements:

```
bzero(msg_incoming, 16);
recv(fd_activeSock, msg_incoming, 16, 0);
printf("%s", msg_incoming);
```

Although `msg_incoming` has been zeroed, when it is populated in the `recv` call, if all 16 elements are populated, there is no guaranteed that the last element of the array was populated with '\0', leaving the buffer as a non-null terminated array.  If that happens, A segfault is likely when `printf()` is called.  Or worse, *[a segfault may not occur](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)*, leading you to believe your code works fine. (AKA undefined behavior)

The fix is to check the return value of *[recv()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/recv.html)*:

```
ssize_t bytes = recv(fd_activeSock, msg_incoming, 16, 0);
if(bytes <= 0)
{
    //handle error/end of message condition
}
else
{
    msg_incoming[bytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s", msg_incoming);
}
```

Additional material on *[Reading data with a socket](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1044780608&answer=1108255660)*.

Answer (score 2):

```
freeaddrinfo(established_SERV_param)
```

Should be called when `established_SERV_param` is obtained by `getaddrinfo`. Here `established_SERV_param` is probably a stack variable. Hence, you are trying to free a pointer to stack variable.

Umm something is wrong in your program. Since, `freeaddrinfo` expects a pointer but it is a variable since you use `&` in call to `accept`. Removing the call to `freeaddrinfo` may fix it.

If above is not enough then it is important to see how `msg_incoming` is defined/allocated. It should not be a `const` char array or initialised by a string literal making it a `const`. If it is a pointer it should be adequately allocated memory using `malloc`.

Analysing core dump:

Compile your code with debug On and optimisation Off

```
gcc -g -O0
```

Then open the core file in `gdb` as

```
gdb <executable> <core file>
(gdb) bt
```

Above, `bt` will show you the back trace where the program crashed. You can go the function it crashed by command `fr 0` and print some variables. A tutorial for gdb can found [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/)

Comment: Mohammad, Thank you for the suggestion. I thought about getting rid of it too. A popular socket programming guide - Beej's guide - provides some sample code where the "at-address" operator is put in front of 'established_SERV_param' [in their case, 'their_addr' when calling accept().
https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html 

5.6. accept()—"Thank you for calling port 3490."